# Should interface be part of a system in use case diagram?

Tags: use-case, diagramming

My system is a soda can machine. You can put a coin and buy soda from this machine. The interface is a keypad and digital screen.

One of my requirements is that the user can put x dollars into machine and then add items to his order. Then, the machine will show him the order total.

That is, "show user order total"
Should I show this in my use case diagram? If yes, then how do i show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not. For several reasons.

1. Use cases are typically used to convey functional requirements. Requirements should be solution-independent. They should outline "what" a system should do but not "how". If you have a given interface that you must operate with, then you'd document that as a constraint, not as a use case. See A. Cockburn, Writing Effective Use Cases, p. 191 "**Mistakes Fixed: Too many user interface details**"
2. Use cases describe the interaction with a system from a user's point of view. You may want to include the system as an actor as well; but then still...:
3. ... the use case you describe would probably be too fine grained. See A. Cockburn, Writing Effective Use Cases, p. 192 "Mistakes Fixed: Very low goal levels"

If you still want to highlight that aspect in your use case diagram (which can be useful depending on your needs) then consider naming the use case "verify order total" and assign it to your primary actor. IMO that would be perfectly fine for a subfunction level.

Answer (score 0):

That depends largely on your requirements; my gut feeling for your example is yes you should.

How you show it also depends on your requirements. If it is necessary to show the order total on a digital screen, include the digital screen. If that part is unspecified (i.e. could be receipt, voice output, interpretive dance) then you just say "show order total (somehow)". It could be as simple as a labelled box or, if your tool lets you, an object that looks like a digital screen.

Comment: I am unable to understand. can you show me what you said in a diagram form?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement you outline should either be included in the Use Case itself or as part of an Activity Diagram which 'explodes' each Use Case.    It is not appropriate to show such a detailed requirement on a Use Case diagram